# Spring: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication not found

Tags: maven, spring-boot

This is my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>SpringBootGame</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringBootGame</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20090211</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.game.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>

</project>
```

I build my jar file by "mvn clean install" and then running the jar file extracted by: 
"java -jar target\SpringBootGame-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar".

Then, I get an error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication
>           at com.game.Main.main(Main.java:15) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           ... 1 more

Do you know what is the problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. you should remove the **maven-jar-plugin**
2. modify spring-boot-maven-plugin to:

   ```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        <configuration>
            <mainClass>com.game.Main</mainClass> 
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
   ```
3. you can execute **mvn package spring-boot:repackage** to generate the executable jar

Comment: In this case I get the error: "no main manifest attribute, in target\SpringBootGame-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"

Comment: try mvn package spring-boot:repackage

Comment: because you didn't configure the pom.xml with spring-boot-starter-parent pom, so the configuration is a little bit complicated

Comment: OK. How can I configure pom.xml with spring-boot-starter-parent ?

Comment: Add this
`<parent>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
      <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
   </parent>`

Comment: you can refer to https://gist.github.com/clevertension/bc4206826403d410d74a74b5da7a7d0e

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem ...
There are a bug on Intellij Idea 2015 and using Gradle v4+...
in shortly:

```
Update youre Intellij Idea to 2017 or later
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution was inspired by @clevertension. However, due to small differences in my plugin configuration, I decided to share if somebody would make use of it.

1. you should remove the maven-jar-plugin
2. modify spring-boot-maven-plugin to:

   ```
        <plugin>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
           <configuration>
               <archive>
                 <manifest>
                   <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                   <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                   <mainClass>com.game.Main</mainClass>
                 </manifest>
               </archive>
           </configuration>
           <executions>
               <execution>
                   <goals>
                       <goal>repackage</goal>
                   </goals>
               </execution>
           </executions>
       </plugin>
   ```
3. you can execute **mvn package spring-boot:repackage**